# Using `.index()` on repeating letters

Tags: python, autocomplete, dictionary

I'm building a function that builds a dictionary with words, such as:

```
{'b': ['b', 'bi', 'bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'],
'bi': ['bi', 'bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'],
'birt': ['birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
'birthda': ['birthda', 'birthday'], 
'birthday': ['birthday'], 
'birth': ['birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'],
'birthd': ['birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
'bir': ['bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday']}
```

This is what it looks like:

```
def add_prefixs(word, prefix_dict):
    lst=[]
    for letter in word:
        n=word.index(letter)
        if n==0:
            lst.append(word[0])
        else:
            lst.append(word[0:n])
    lst.append(word)
    lst.remove(lst[0])
    for elem in lst:
        b=lst.index(elem)
        prefix_dict[elem]=lst[b:]
    return prefix_dict
```

It works great for words like "birthday", but when I have a letter that repeats itself, I have a problem... for example, "hello".

```
{'h': ['h', 'he', 'he', 'hell', 'hello'], 'hell': ['hell', 'hello'], 'hello': ['hello'], 'he': ['he', 'he', 'hell', 'hello']}
```

I know it's because of the index (python chooses the index of the first time the letter appears) but I do not know how to solve it. Yes, this is my homework and I'm really trying to learn from you guys :)

Comment: @Yarden: That's because I replaced the tabs with spaces for you. The editor uses 8 spaces for tabs, while the code renders with only 4 spaces, causing your indentation to be off for the first line you manually indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already loop over the word; instead of using `.index()` keep a counter. Python makes that very easy for you; use the `enumerate()` function:

```
for n, letter in enumerate(word):
    if n==0:
        lst.append(word[0])
    else:
        lst.append(word[0:n])
```

Now you are no longer *using* the `letter` variable though, so just `range(len(word)` instead:

```
for n in range(len(word)):
    if n==0:
        lst.append(word[0])
    else:
        lst.append(word[0:n])
```

We can simplify this down to a list comprehension:

```
lst = [word[0:max(n, 1)] for n in range(len(word))]
```

Note the `max()` there; instead of testing if `n` is 0, we set a minimum of `1` for the slice.

Since you then proceed to *remove* the first entry again (since it is the same as the second result) *and* you add the full word, just add 1 to the `n` counter instead:

```
lst = [word[0:n+1] for n in range(len(word))]
```

The second half of your function *can* use the `enumerate()` function effectively, instead of `.index()`:

```
for b, elem in enumerate(lst):
    prefix_dict[elem]=lst[b:]
```

Now your function is a lot simpler; note that there is no need to *return* `prefix_dict` since you are manipulating that in-place:

```
def add_prefixs(word, prefix_dict):
    lst = [word[0:n+1] for n in range(len(word))]
    for b, elem in enumerate(lst):
        prefix_dict[elem]=lst[b:]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to simplify your solution by thinking in terms of indices rather than letters. Normally in Python, we loop over values, as that is what we care about. Here, we are actually generating prefixes to the string, where the content doesn't matter, but rather, the position does:

```
def prefixes(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        yield seq[:i+1]

segments = list(prefixes("birthday"))
print({segment: segments[start:] for start, segment in enumerate(segments)})
```

What you really want is to get each prefix of your word, which we can do in a rare case where looping through indices is a valid option, as that is what we are trying to do.

We then use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to select the right 'children' groups for each segment.

Which gives us (with some added white-space for clarity):

```
{
    'birt': ['birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'bir': ['bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'birthday': ['birthday'], 
    'bi': ['bi', 'bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'birthda': ['birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'b': ['b', 'bi', 'bir', 'birt', 'birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'birthd': ['birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday'], 
    'birth': ['birth', 'birthd', 'birthda', 'birthday']
}
```

If you didn't mind some extra looping, we can even simplify it down to:

```
def prefixes(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        segment = word[:i+1]
        yield segment, [segment[:i+1] for i in range(len(segment))]

print(dict(prefixes("birthday")))
```

As a side note, another implementation for `prefixes()` is:

```
def prefixes(seq):
    return prefixes(seq[:-1])+[seq] if seq else []
```

However, this is a recursive function and as Python isn't optimized for recursion, this is a worse way of doing it. It also creates a list rather than a generator, which is less memory-efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn [was faster than me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589002/296974), but I have some additions:

```
def add_prefixs(word, prefix_dict):
    lst=[]
    for n, letter in enumerate(word):
        if n > 0:
            lst.append(word[0:n])
    lst.append(word)
    for elem in lst:
        b=lst.index(elem)
        prefix_dict[elem]=lst[b:]
    return prefix_dict
```

Why put the 0th entry if you remove it immediately?

Another simplification could be

```
def add_prefixs(word, prefix_dict):
    #lst=[word[0:n] for n, letter in enumerate(word) if n > 0] + [word]
    # why do I think so complicated? Better use
    lst=[word[0:n+1] for n, letter in enumerate(word)]
    prefix_dict.update((elem, lst[b:]) for b, elem in enumerate(lst))
    return prefix_dict
```

---

With a class like

```
class Segments(object):
    def __init__(self, string, minlength=1):
        self.string = string
        self.minlength = minlength
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        s = self.string[:self.minlength + index]
        if len(s) < self.minlength + index: raise IndexError
        if index >= len(self): raise IndexError # alternatively
        return s
    def cut(self, num):
        return type(self)(self.string, self.minlength + num)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(list(self))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.string) - self.minlength + 1
```

you can further simplify:

```
def add_prefixes(word, prefix_dict):
    lst = Segments(word)
    prefix_dict.update((prefix, lst.cut(n)) for n, prefix in enumerate(lst))
    return prefix_dict
```

Hm. If I think about it again, this is no simplification. But it avoids having many copies of essentially the same data or parts of them...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most *pythonic* approach is:

```
def add_prefixs(word, prefix_dict):
    lst = [word[0:n+1] for n in range(len(word))]
    prefix_dict.update((k, lst[n:]) for n, k in enumerate(lst))
```